# Android error:method gettext must be called from the ui thread currently inferred thread is working

Tags: android, text-to-speech, microsoft-translator

Hi All I am new to Android and I was building an English to German translator app and I am getting the above error for following the line of code:
Can please assist me how to resolve this issue.

```
package com.exmaple.android.lang_trans;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;

import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;

import android.util.Log;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.TextView;

import com.exmaple.android.lang_trans.R;

import com.memetix.mst.language.Language;

import com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnInitListener {

    private TextToSpeech tts;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.bSpeak)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                speakOut(((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTranslatedText)).getText().toString());
            }
        });

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.bTranslate)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                class bgStuff extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

                    String translatedText = "";

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try {
                            //below line is throwing the error
                            String text = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserText)).getText().toString();
                            translatedText = translate(text);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            translatedText = e.toString();
                        }

                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTranslatedText)).setText(translatedText);
                        super.onPostExecute(result);
                    }

                }

                new bgStuff().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    public String translate(String text) throws Exception {


        // Set the Client ID / Client Secret once per JVM. It is set statically and applies to all services
        Translate.setClientId("CLIENT ID"); //Change this
        Translate.setClientSecret("CLIENT SECRET"); //change


        String translatedText = "";

        translatedText = Translate.execute(text, Language.GERMAN);

        return translatedText;
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.GERMAN);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else {

                //speakOut("Ich");
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }
    }

    private void speakOut(String text) {
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are accessing your UI element in a thread other than the UI thread which android system does not allow

> you cannot update the UI from any thread other than the UI thread or the "main" thread.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads

So you could change your onClick function to the following :

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.bTranslate)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        class bgStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    if (params.length > 0) {
                        return translate(params[0]);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return e.toString();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTranslatedText)).setText(result);
            }
        }

        new bgStuff().execute(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserText)).getText().toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Aravinda if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.